# "The starting lineup to the Lakers"

Tags: prepositions

I was watching the show *The American Bible Challenge*, and heard Jeff Foxworthy say:

> They have written all the books of the Old Testament, all the books of the New Testament, the Ten Commandments, and I'm pretty sure the starting lineup **to** the Lakers on this right here.

The preposition **to** sounded kind of jarring here. I would've used **of** and said "the starting lineup **of** the Lakers." Google searches for "the starting lineup **to**" doesn't show much, while "the starting lineup **of**" seems to be much more common. Can **to** be used here at all?

Comment: Unrelated question: As he says "on this right here" is he pointing at or displaying something with writing on it?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, that's right. He unfolds a piece of paper towel as he says that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anecdotal evidence from someone who has lived in the US South for a short while, but has lived in Pennsylvania for most of his life: I would consider **to** something of a southernism in that particular locution.

> Here is the starting lineup to the 1984 Talladega 500.

But **to** can indeed express the notion of integral relationship, part-to-whole:

> What's that you have in your hand?
>   --It's the propellor to the model airplane Billy's putting together.
>
> --It's the outer foam cover to an earbud.
>
> -- It's the portafilter to an Italian espresso machine made in the 1960s for home use.
>
> --It's a sheet of paper with the starting lineup to the Lakers.

Answer (score 3):

Either could be used, although 'starting lineup of' is currently the more popular phrase of the two.  However, my immediate thought on reading this was that I would have used 'starting lineup for'. I ran an Ngram on all three phrases and 'starting linup for' is the most popular of the three. I have restricted Ngram to American English as this is a question that has an American context. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20starting%20lineup%20of%2Cthe%20starting%20lineup%20to%2Cthe%20starting%20lineup%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20starting%20lineup%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20starting%20lineup%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20starting%20lineup%20for%3B%2Cc0)